# Laravel 7 Artisan error - Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

First of all I am kind of new in Laravel but I do like to learn and I really need your help fixing this error.

my project is cloned from my GitHub and all the steps i think I have done them as by the book :) however running Laravel installation at the end I've got the error

to be more specified.

1. config.php is not present in config folder (in order to try as one suggestion rename it as config_ )
2. I did tried without success all commands suggested in different resolutions
   php artisan cache:clear
   composer update
   composer dump-autoload

[error right after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uyp5.png)

[error trying artisan with bellow code live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2d5k.png)

I have read I think all of posts in regarding of this errors and trying all possibilities and actually found something but from here I've got stack

I understand that can be somewhere used url() or asset() - is the way I found the code bellow which is containing asset() and provoking this error but don't know what to use instead...

If I do get rid of the codes having asset in adminlte.php than artisan is working... any help on the correct code (how to replace those 3 asset add or what to change like for dummies :) will be much appreciated

```
    [
        'name' => 'SummerNote',
        'active' => true,
        'files' => [
            [
                'type' => 'css',
                'asset' => false,
                'location' => asset('vendor/summernote/summernote-bs4.css'),
            ],
            [
                'type' => 'js',
                'asset' => false,
                'location' => asset('vendor/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js')
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
    'name' => 'BsCustomFileInput',
    'active' => true,
    'files' => [
        [
            'type' => 'js',
            'asset' => false,
            'location' => asset('vendor/bs-custom-file-input/bs-custom-file-input.min.js')
        ]
    ]
]
```

]
];

[code in configs/adminlte.php for artisan run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JxKh.png)

Thank you in advance if needed any other details I will be happy to provide and to have this fixed with your help.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what piece of code is causing a problem. That code should be in your question.

Comment: @miken32 thank you for your quick answer as I said I am new on Laravel, please can you be more specified or even give me a code line which can help me on this? Do you mean I need to change something on line 65 of the error message path? but what? this is my code in that path and on line 65. Thank you in advance
            $app->instance('routes', $routes);
            return new UrlGenerator(
                $routes, $app->rebinding(
                    'request', $this->requestRebinder()
line65                ), $app['config']['app.asset_url']
            );
        });

Answer (score 4):

this error generally occurs when you use a helper function to generate the url in your configuration files. Routing url generator also uses these helper functions so when you use this function inside of the config files then the url generator does not understand if it has to be rendered or simply taken as a string.  Please make sure that you are not using any **url()** or **asset()** or other helpers functions inside your configuration files. use **env()** function to write your url  or other function. and path functions like **public_path()** and **storage_path()** for directories